# Server wan't send mail when using Google Mail service

Tags: email, gmail, vps

Situation:

Email MX service is on example.com BUT using google mail service.
A domain (web service) are on different IP address than google mail service on VPS host and on the same domain name example.com.

host example.com

```
   example.com has address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx   <--- VPS server, WEB service
   example.com mail is handled by 5 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
   example.com mail is handled by 1 aspmx.l.google.com.
   example.com mail is handled by 5 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
   example.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx3.googlemail.com.
   example.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx2.googlemail.com.
```

host -t mx example.com

```
example.com mail is handled by 5 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
example.com mail is handled by 1 aspmx.l.google.com.
example.com mail is handled by 5 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
example.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx3.googlemail.com.
example.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx2.googlemail.com.
```

On a same domain `example.com` we are using MX service google mail service.

PROBLEM: On a VPS server `example.com has address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` a VPS server can't send an email to another `something@example.com` as a same domain.

WHAT I WANT? Using mail service MX from googlemail and VPS from another IP address.

And dig -t example.com

> ; <<>> DiG 9.9.2-P1 <<>> example.com ;; global options: +cmd ;; Got
>   answer: ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 8318 ;;
>   flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
>
> ;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION: ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512 ;; QUESTION
>   SECTION: ;example.com.            IN  A
>
> ;; ANSWER SECTION: example.com.       7200    IN  A   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
>
> ;; Query time: 208 msec ;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1) ;; WHEN:
>   Sun Jul  7 13:25:21 2013 ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 52

**Sending mail from google service can send to ALL.
Send mail from VPS server can send to ALL EXCEPT on the `example.com`**

Hint: CentOS using Plesk service with full VPS SSH access. What is best solution for working mail service on both and that can VPS send mail service on a same domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using SMTP to connect another host and [PHPMailer](https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/).

Answer (score 0):

Your vps should authenticate with gmail before sending the email.  Configure your software to use gmail as a smarthost for delivery and you should be fine.   You will need to provide gmail credentials in the configuration.

Look in the `/var/log` directory for recently the logs of what is happening.  `syslog` and `mail.log` are likely to have details.

Comment: But what's about adding another MX record list in MX domain on VPS server? If google MX recored is primarly, another lists should try as MX 15 example.com ? There are not logs. I remembered that when I send from shell that tell me can't send mail from same domain, something like this, but when I send to another it works and sent.

Comment: MX records indicate which server receives e-mail.  MTA (which send email) don't need an MX record.  You likely want all your MX records to point to Google servers.  It sounds like you have not setup your server to use a smarthost, which should solve the failure to send to the same domain.

Comment: It's looks like I need to try these settings to change and point to google? http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/configure-sendmail-as-a-smart-host/

Comment: Those will work if you have `sendmail` as your email service.  I suspect you may have `postfix` as your email service.  It uses different configuration files, but the principle is the same.